# Can't figure out a way to integrate $\int_{A}\log(\sin(x-y))dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm  having trouble computing the integral $\int_{A}\log(\sin(x-y))dx dy$, where $A$ is the triangle defined by the 3 eqations: $x = \pi, y = x ,y = 0$

I tried the substition $u = x-y, v = x+y$ and got:

$$\frac{-1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{v}\log(\sin u))du dv$$

I'm quite new at this, so there's a possibility I've made a silly mistake, or I'm just not getting something obvious about how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral you are dealing with is:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^x \ln(\sin(x-y))\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^x \ln(\sin y)\,dy\,dx$$
Changing the order of integration:
$$\int_0^{\pi} \int_y^{\pi} \ln(\sin y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{\pi} (\pi-y)\ln(\sin y)\,dy=I$$
$I$ is equivalent to:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi}y\ln(\sin y)\,dy$$ 
Add the two expressions for $I$ and you get:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \ln(\sin y)\,dy=\boxed{-\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}\ln 2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is the first equation justified? i.e., why does $sin(x-y)$ become $sin(y)$? Also, what allows you to change the order of integration? I thought that Fubini's theroem only allows this in the case of a rectangle domain.

Comment: @Robert: I used the property of definite integrals which states that:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$$
About your second question, I am not sure what you ask. Do you mean changing the order of integration is invalid here? I am not sure about the correct terminology in double integrals.

Comment: Why is it possible to integrate by x and then by y instead of by y and then by x? I know that in that case of a rectangle domain (not a triangle like here) it is possible to switch the order of integration by Fubini's theorem. Why is it justified when the domain is a triangle?

Comment: @Robert: I didn't know if there was a theorem governing the change of order of integration in double integrals. I did it based on my intuition. I am sorry, I can't help with that. :(

Comment: You're probably correct anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Robert, you can always extend your function from a triangle to a square by setting the function equal to zero outside the triangle. You then apply Fubini's theorem and/or Tonelli's theorem to the square.

Comment: Does this work only for functions that are symmetrical in relation to $y  = x$?

Comment: @Robert You extend the function by padding it with zero, not symmetrically. It works for any measurable function.

Comment: What does it mean to pad it with zero? I make it 0 anyplace outside of the triangle? How does that work? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: More specifically, in this case, wouldn't I still have to integrate differently in the triangle and outside of it?